# Download File from Amazon S3 Bucket in Titanium

Tags: iphone, ios, amazon-s3, titanium, titanium-mobile

I would like to know the method to download a file object from Amazon S3 Bucket using Appcelerator Titanium.

Can anyone help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to download a specific known file, or the complete bucket?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var downloadingFileUrl = "Url of the file that need to be downloaded"

//File path where downloaded file will be saved
var fileSavingPath = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,"file_Path");

 //Define the http client
 var myHttpClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

//On success of downloading
myHttpClient.onload = function(){

 //Write the file to the desired path
fileSavingPath.write(httpClient.responseData);
};

//Open the url to download
myHttpClient.open("GET",  downloadingFileUrl);

//Send request
 myHttpClient.send(null);
```